# How to get all the values of particular column of kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

i have kendo grid with 4 columns in it 
`[mac,level,timestamp,message]`.
i need to store all the values under `timestamp` column in an array.I tried but couldn't find any way to traverse in a particular column. Any idea how to do this using java script?

Comment: how about looping through all data on your grid datasource get the timestamp, and push them to an array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're using kendo which you must include **jQuery**. To make life easier why don't try to use **jQuery**, as per my suggestion at the moment i don't know any other way but to

- get & loop through the grid datasource
- get the date and push it into an array

For example i create button `<button id="test">Click here</button>` and kendo console `<div class="console"><div>` so you can see the result after clicking the button. Here goes the code :

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    var arrayDate = [];
    var data =$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._data;
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      arrayDate.push(data[i].OrderDate);
    }  
    kendoConsole.log(arrayDate);
});
```

Here is working example for you on [kendo dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IJocU)

Answer (score 3):

You can access your data through Grid's data source and grab it manually, something like this should work :

```
function getGridTimestamps() {
    var grid = $("#grid").getKendoGrid(),
        datas = grid.dataSource.data();

    return $.map(datas, function(data) {
        return data.timestamp;
    });
}

var timestamps = getGridTimestamps();
```